# Comparing every 4th weeks values in SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql

What I have been trying to do is compare every 4 weeks we receive a payment but I need to know if that value changes (higher or Lower) and what the new values are and what the old value was.

Ive been trying to use a case Statement but I cant get my head around it.

Below is my table which I need to compare. (there would be multiple account numbers in this table)

[image: MyTable]

What I sort of need to see is the results would be:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really only need a `CASE` expression for your `Y\N` change column. `LAG` will do all the rest of the heavy lifting for you.

The `COALESCE` in the `CASE` is just there to indicate no change when there's no comparison value.

You *could* wrap more `CASE` expressions around the last columns to only display them if there are differences, but that's really a job for the presentation layer, not the data layer.

This yields your desired results, but I won't chew up screen space with the output.

```
SELECT
  v.AcctNum 
 ,v.WkNum
 ,v.Amt
 ,CASE
    WHEN v.Amt = COALESCE(LAG(v.Amt, 4) OVER (PARTITION BY v.AcctNum ORDER BY v.WkNum), v.Amt)
      THEN 'No'
    ELSE 'Yes'
  END AS Changed
 ,v.Amt AS OldValue
 ,LAG(v.Amt, 4) OVER (PARTITION BY v.AcctNum ORDER BY v.WkNum) AS NewValue
FROM
  (
    VALUES 
      (10586,'201901', -330.14)
     ,(10586,'201902', 0)
     ,(10586,'201903', 0)
     ,(10586,'201904', 0)
     ,(10586,'201905', -425.84)
     ,(10586,'201906', 0)
     ,(10586,'201907', 0)
     ,(10586,'201908', 0)
     ,(10586,'201909', -425.84)
     ,(10586,'201910', 0)
     ,(10586,'201911', 0)
     ,(10586,'201912', 0)
     ,(10586,'201913', -335.12)
     ,(2,'201901', -130.14)
     ,(2,'201902', 0)
     ,(2,'201903', 0)
     ,(2,'201904', 0)
     ,(2,'201905', -225.84)
     ,(2,'201906', 0)
     ,(2,'201907', 0)
     ,(2,'201908', 0)
     ,(2,'201909', -225.84)
     ,(2,'201910', 0)
     ,(2,'201911', 0)
     ,(2,'201912', 0)
     ,(2,'201913', -235.12)
  ) AS v (AcctNum, WkNum, Amt);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `LAG()` function to find "week-4" number (assuming there is data for all weeks) - for multiple accounts you will have to add `partition by` to `over` clause. How it works, see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).
I do not know logic for showing/not showing data for particular week so I did not include this in my answer.

```
with s as (
    select v.weekNum, v.amount, LAG(v.weekNum, 4)over(order by v.weekNum) refWeekNum
    from (values('201901','2.3'),('201902','3.6'),('201903','9.9'),('201904','8.7'),('201905','10.8'),('201906','8.5'),('201907','10.4'),('201908','10.8'),('201909','4.1'),('201910','8.4'),('201911','5.5'),('201912','5.2'),('201913','4.1'),('201914','5.5'),('201915','5.1'),('201916','5.8'),('201917','2.3'),('201918','10.1'),('201919','10.1'),('201920','9.9'),('201921','3.8'),('201922','3.2'),('201923','1.3'),('201924','2.3'),('201925','1.5'),('201926','5.10'),('201927','3.6'),('201928','9.9'),('201929','10.7'),('201930','4.8'))v(weekNum,amount)
)
select s.weekNum, s.amount, s.refWeekNum, ref.amount refAmount
from s
    left outer join s ref on s.refWeekNum = ref.weekNum
```

Comment: Take another look at the output from your query. The refweeks and refamounts don't seem to line up.

Comment: Thanks, I messed up aliases - edit made to the answer